# What is wrong with my strings?

Tags: ruby, string-literals

The following code is generating an error and I cannot see the issue. Can anyone help?

```
customer_array = [‘Ken’,’William’,’Catherine’,’Mark’,’Steve’,’Sam’]
customer_hash = {
‘Ken’ => ‘Fiction’,
‘William’ => ‘Mystery’,
‘Catherine’ => ‘Computer’,
‘Mark’ => ‘Fiction’,
‘Steve’ => ‘Sports’,
‘Sam’ => ‘Fiction’
}
# => customer_array.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG , expecting '}'
# 'William' => 'Mystery'
#      ^
```

Comment: have you tried double quote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be with those weird back quotes. Try this instead:

```
customer_array = ["Ken","William","Catherine","Mark","Steve","Sam"]
customer_hash = {
    "Ken" => "Fiction",
    "William" => "Mystery",
    "Catherine" => "Computer",
    "Mark" => "Fiction",
    "Steve" => "Sports",
    "Sam" => "Fiction"
}
```

Comment: You can also use single quotes, as @slivu said in his answer. Single quote or double quote works, but backquote doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

your quotes are non-ASCII chars.

replace them with ASCII `'` or `"`.

or add `# encoding: UTF-8` to the beginning of your file and wrap them into ASCII quotes, like this:

```
# encoding: UTF-8

customer_hash = {
  "‘Ken’" => "‘Fiction’",
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have lots of keys => values a hash contains one key (before the arrow) and one value (after the arrow)

You can make an array of hashes. Ruby on rails uses this.

You have to fix the quotes

```
customer_hash = {
    "Ken" => "Fiction",
    "William" => "Mystery",
    "Catherine" => "Computer",
    "Mark" => "Fiction",
    "Steve" => "Sports",
    "Sam" => "Fiction"
}
```

But why not do it like this

```
customer_array_of_hashes =  [
{'Ken' => 'Fiction'},
{'William' => 'Mystery'},
{'Catherine' => 'Computer'},
{'Mark' => 'Fiction'},
{'Steve'=> 'Sports'},
{'Sam' => 'Fiction'}
]
```

Then You can loop trough it like this

```
customer_array_of_hashes.each do|hash|
 hash.each do |key, value|
  puts "lastname: " + value + ", firstname: " + key
 end
end
```

You can find alot of all methods on all ruby Classes here

[Ruby API](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/)

And rails extra methods here

[Ruby on rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/)

One tip in the end

Try this

```
irb(main):039:0> customer_array_of_hashes.class
=> Array
```

If you ever wounder what class you have in ruby the class method will give the answer.

Ok you know that customer_array_of_hashes is an array. One method you can use on arrays is .first

Try this

```
irb(main):040:0> customer_array_of_hashes.first.class
=> Hash
```

Ok it is an array of hashes!

Good look!